# How do I change a UIButton's title using KVC?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, key-value, key-value-coding, kvc

I have an array of UIButtons and want to set all their titles to a specific value at once, **without looping** through the array. The only solution I've found is by means of Key-Value Coding, i.e. something like this:

```
[self.board setValue:@"X" forKeyPath:@"titleLabel.text"];
```

However, the button's **titleLabel** property is readonly and cannot be changed. I also tried using the button's **title** property as the keypath, but it doesn't work either.

I've done this before by changing the "enabled" property of all the buttons at once using KVC and it worked great, but if I want to change the titles it just won't work (I'm assuming this is because of the new ControlState feature of the UIButton which allows multiple titles for its various states).

So, does anyone have a one-liner solution (with no loops) to change the title of every button from the array?

Comment: The simplest way is a loop, what's your issue with using loops?

Comment: Well, I really like using KVC, and I just cannot believe that there is no way of setting a button's title using KVC.. plus, the code looks cleaner this way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, KVC is working and is setting your text value.  From the Apple Documentation: **Although this property is read-only, its own properties are read/write. Use these properties to configure the appearance of the button label** So textLabel is a *UILabel* and the *text* property on *UILabel* is not read only. The reason it does not appear to be working is that you are only changing the text of UILabel and not the frame size of the label which has a default value of     (0, 0, 0, 0).  If you initialise your buttons with a default value of "(*three blanks*)" for instance (rather than *nil*) then it will work.  (However, there does still seem to be an issue where iOS resets the button value to it's initial value after you click on it)

Comment: Well, the problem is that there's no need for any configuration, because the array is an IBOutletCollection of buttons that were already created in Interface Builder.. so they do have frames and all the required configuration. And still, I've seen many others saying that setting the titleLabel.text property is not having any effect whatsoever.

Comment: Yes, the UIButton does have a frame but not the UILabel which is the titleLabel property of the UIButton.  If you use the debugger and **po [[self.boards lastObject] titleLabel]** after you call your KVC method you will see that it has a text property of "X" but a frame of (0,0,0,0)

Comment: OK, I understood now. So the follow-up question would be: how do I set the frame of all buttons' titleLabel using KVC? ツ

Comment: Well, I don't think you can set it directly as it does not have a _frame_ property, but, as I said, you can make sure the frame is already sufficiently large enough to display your text by giving it a blank title.  You can do this in Interface Builder by just typing three blanks where it says _title_

Comment: Yeah, it does seem to do the trick, however there are some weird consequences of doing the empty spaces thing: if I use 3 spaces, the button's text is shifted to the left, and if I use 2 spaces the text gets cut off :( So in the end, iterating through the array seems to be the only solution.. anyway, thank you so much for pointing these details out, learned a lot!

Comment: Now in late 2018, Apple Documentation says also: `To set the actual text of the label, use setTitle:forState: (button.titleLabel.text does not let you set the text)`. So it tells you to not do that

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with subclassing, you can make your button KVC compliant for a title attribute. For your purpose, implementing `-set<Key>:` method is enough, but here in Swift, you can implement both `-<key>` and `-set<Key>:` by defining one computed property.

```
class KVCButton: UIButton {

    var titleForNormalState: String? {
        get {
            return titleForState(.Normal)
        }
        set {
            setTitle(newValue, forState: .Normal)
        }
    }
}
```

Then just call `[self.board setValue:@"X" forKeyPath:@"titleForNormalState"];`.

You can find more on ensuring KVC compliance [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Compliant.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002172-BAJEAIEE).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old question, but I use a solution to set textColor for IBOutletCollection(UIButton); and It is similar to set text to button;

As John Dalton mentioned, button properties are readonly so there is no way to use KVC; But It is possible if you define a new property by category to UIButton and then add text(in my case text color) by KVC;

Add New File-> Select Objective-c File

Name: Property (it is your choice)

File Type: Category

Class: UIButton

Two file with name  *UIButton+Property.h/.m* will be create

.h

```
@interface UIButton (Property)

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIColor *textColor;

- (void)setTextColor:(UIColor *)textColor;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "UIButton+Property.h"

@implementation UIButton (Property)


- (void)setTextColor:(UIColor *)textColor {
    [self setTitleColor:textColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

- (UIColor *)textColor {
    return self.textColor;
}
@end
```

In class:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *preLoginLbls;
```

.
.
.

```
[_preLoginBtns setValue:TEXT_COLOR forKey:@"textColor"];
```