# How to set UILabel properties like textcolor, font etc using KVC?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, kvc

I need to know how to set `UILabel` properties like text color, font, alignment etc using KVC. In the below link there is an example on how to set `UIButton` title label text. 
[How do I change a UIButton's title using KVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389410/how-do-i-change-a-uibuttons-title-using-kvc)

In view with that I have tried like this:

```
NSDictionary *labelProperties = @{@"textColor":@"redColor", @"font":@"Helvetica"},@"frame":@"50,50,50,50", @"text":@"Hi....", @"backgroundColor":@"yellowColor"};
UILabel*myLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
[myLabel setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:labelProperties];
[self.view addSubview:myLabel];
```

But it didn't work. Application got crashed. I hope it's due to the incorrect value for the keys. What should be the format of the values, so that the above code works. I need to set all the UI attributes like this.

Is there any tutorial by which I can understand how to set the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to set all of the values to strings when the actual values required are obviously not strings.

Try this part and work up from there:

```
NSDictionary *labelProperties = @{@"textColor":[UIColor redColor]}
```

Comment: I cannot use that. I am getting all the values from server and they are of string type. What I need is a proper format for the string values so that I can use it directly

Comment: @Pallavi: There is no "proper format for string values". The *keys* are always strings in KVC, but the *values* are not. "textColor" is a   UIColor, "font" is a UIFont, "frame" is a CGRect, ...